# Rest-assured test cases on Jenkins as part of github PR acceptance

Tags: spring-boot, github, jenkins, rest-assured

I have a springboot project and I have written rest-assured test cases to test my APIs. I want those to run as part of my PR acceptance from GitHub. But my issue is I am not able to figure out how can I build, deploy temporarily (or on some test instance) and run rest-assured cases. If anyone can please help me do this using Jenkins and Github?

Normal jenkins pipeline with Github PR builder runs the test case for me during PR raise but all the restassured test cases run on current deployed instance (as they should because rest-aasured only requires URL).
PS: I don't want to test on mock services I want to test on real service.

Comment: Include rest assured tests to your service test code and access it with localhost